# RecyclerView not scrolling smoothly, when I try to load Image+text of size 1000

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to load list of size 1000 to my recyclerview. I am seeing lag and my recyclerview does not scroll smoothly.

My Recyclerview item has both text and image. Please let me know how can I increase smoothness while scrolling

Below is my  `onBindHolderHolder` method

```
       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull My_View_Holder holder, int position) {
            holder.textView8.setText(arr_symbol_list.get(position));
            holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.eight_four);
    /*
            if(position==0)
                holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
            if(position==1)
                holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
            if(position==2)
                holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
            if(position==3)
                holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
            if(position==4)
                holder.imageView8.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
            if(position==5)

}
```

Comment: Do you have `pagination` enabled? are you getting your `items` from `API(webservice)`

Comment: no sir recycler imageResource getting from Resource/drawable

Comment: are you saving 1000 images in your `drawable`? that is not good considering your apk size also and also it affects performance. Suitable option for you is to load less items at once i.e enable `pagination`

Comment: but sir all 1000 images size less than 300 kb means not hiigh resolution images we saved inside drawable

Comment: I would also suggest using an image library like Glide or Picasso. They handle images much smoother than doing so on your own.

Comment: sir my hint is ... whenever program control  inside onBindViewHolder that time our 1000 codition available its take time for setting images

Comment: @AjayPawar you have to work on your logic and avoid those conditions and not have so much conditions and also as Sammy suggested use image loading libraries to load images

Comment: its only hint sir i dont know what happenig actually